# flatbuffer 2.0.6 couldn't generate golang file on macos big sur 11.4

Tags: flatbuffers

[image: for some reason my flatc successfully generate rust file but couldn't generate golang file]

for some reason my flatc successfully generate rust file but couldn't generate golang file. I am using flatc version 2.0.6 on macOS big sur 11.4. anyone encounter same issue?

Comment: Probably easier to ask this question on the FlatBuffers repo.

Comment: looking at the code, the generator fails if it can't save a file: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/8468eab83bacc8bbd6cb5ae22197af06a9437b2d/src/idl_gen_go.cpp#L1371 I am not sure why that would be.. permissions? then again, that would make Rust fail too, unless Rust generates no directories maybe. Can you try `--java`? check your permissions?

Comment: We should have a specific error message for that, for sure.